# How can I reuse a Django view with a post method for my API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am currently trying to create an API with DRF on my backend for a mobile application.

I would like to know if it is possible to reuse some POST methods already implemented by passing them a request as parameter.

Thank you,

Here is the view in question:

The method I am interested in is the POST method.

```
class ShopModuleCategoryCreateView(ShopModuleMixin, BorgiaView):
    """
    """

    permission_required_self = 'modules.change_config_selfsalemodule'
    permission_required_operator = 'modules.change_config_operatorsalemodule'
    menu_type = 'shops'
    template_name = 'modules/shop_module_category_create.html'

    def __init__(self):
        #logger.error(' __init__')
        super().__init__()
        self.shop = None
        self.module_class = None
        self.form_class = None

    def has_permission(self):
        has_perms = super().has_permission()
        if not has_perms:
            return False
        else:
            self.form_class = formset_factory(wraps(ModuleCategoryCreateForm)(
                partial(ModuleCategoryCreateForm, shop=self.shop)), extra=1)
            return True

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        permet d'afficher la page de vente
        """
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['cat_form'] = self.form_class()
        context['cat_name_form'] = ModuleCategoryCreateNameForm(
            initial={'order': self.module.categories.all().count()})
        return render(request, self.template_name, context=context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Permet de publier la creation d'une nouvelle categorie

        cat_name_form => renvoie une objet Form avec le nom et l'ordre entré
        self.module => Module de vente en libre service du magasin Pi
        """

        cat_name_form = ModuleCategoryCreateNameForm(request.POST)

        f = open("myfile.txt", "a")
        f.write(str(request))

        if cat_name_form.is_valid():
            category = Category.objects.create(
                name=cat_name_form.cleaned_data['name'],
                order=cat_name_form.cleaned_data['order'],
                module=self.module,
                shop_id=self.shop.pk,
                category_image=cat_name_form.cleaned_data['category_image'],

            )
            logger.error(self.shop.id)

        cat_form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        for product_form in cat_form.cleaned_data:
            try:
                product = Product.objects.get(
                    pk=product_form['product'].split('/')[0])
                if product.unit:
                    quantity = int(product_form['quantity'])
                else:
                    quantity = 1
                CategoryProduct.objects.create(
                    category=category,
                    product=product,
                    quantity=quantity
                )
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                pass
            except KeyError:
                pass
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        """
        Permet de ...

        self.module_class => self_sales
        self.shop.pk => affiche bien la pk du shop en question 
        """
        #logger.error(' get_success_url')
        # logger.error(self.shop.pk)
        return reverse('url_shop_module_config',
                       kwargs={'shop_pk': self.shop.pk, 'module_class': self.module_class})
```

I tried the following code, I don't know if it's a good thing or if there is a better way to do it ?

```
class TestPost(views.APIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def __init__(self):

        request = WSGIRequest({
            'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST',
            'wsgi.input': StringIO(),
        })

        request.POST = QueryDict('csrfmiddlewaretoken=x9ceGh2r5yxBot8dqY4rBgKpOMCmqUzpSM937ZoBZ93TA0jRyHzfb5lDPpEfrUA0&name=cat0&order=3&category_image=image&form-TOTAL_FORMS=2&form-INITIAL_FORMS=0&form-MIN_NUM_FORMS=0&form-MAX_NUM_FORMS=1000&form-0-product=6/unit&form-0-quantity=123&form-1-product=5/unit&form-1-quantity=258', mutable=True)

        a= ShopModuleCategoryCreateView()
        
        a.has_permission()
        
        a.post(request=request)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to move your business logic to a dedicated method in `services.py` and use the new method in your API view and your existing django view.

The following code is just a draft to show the intention, it may not be copy'n'paste ready and working. But the idea should be clear what to do.

`services.py`

```py
def service_function(shop, module, category_name=None, category_order=None, category_image=None, cat_form_cleaned_data=None):
    if category_name and category_order and category_image:
        category = Category.objects.create(
            name=category_name,
            order=category_order,
            module=module,
            shop_id=shop.pk,
            category_image=category_image,
         )
        logger.error(shop.id)


    for product_form in (cat_form_cleaned_data or []):
        try:
            product = Product.objects.get(
                pk=product_form['product'].split('/')[0])
            if product.unit:
                quantity = int(product_form['quantity'])
            else:
                quantity = 1
            CategoryProduct.objects.create(
                category=category,
                product=product,
                quantity=quantity
            )
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

`views.py`

```py
class ShopModuleCategoryCreateView(ShopModuleMixin, BorgiaView):
    # your existing code ...

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Permet de publier la creation d'une nouvelle categorie

        cat_name_form => renvoie une objet Form avec le nom et l'ordre entré
        self.module => Module de vente en libre service du magasin Pi
        """

        f = open("myfile.txt", "a")
        f.write(str(request))

        cat_name_form = ModuleCategoryCreateNameForm(request.POST)

        category_name = None
        category_order = None
        category_image = None
        if cat_name_form.is_valid():
            cat_form = self.form_class(request.POST)
            category_name=cat_name_form.cleaned_data['name']
            category_order=cat_name_form.cleaned_data['order']
            category_image=cat_name_form.cleaned_data['category_image']

        service_function(
            shop=self.shop,
            module=self.module,
            category_name=cat_name_form.cleaned_data['name'],
            category_order=cat_name_form.cleaned_data['order'],
            category_image=cat_name_form.cleaned_data['category_image'],
            cat_form_cleaned_data=cat_form.cleaned_data,
        )

        return redirect(self.get_success_url())

    # your code ...
```

`api/views.py`

```py
class TestPost(views.APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request):
        # add your code to determine the data from the API request
        service_function(shop, module, category_name, category_order, category_image, cat_form_cleaned_data, ...)
        # your API code
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, with small changes it works !